# Rails 6 [Webpacker] Compiling... takes longs time in development enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, compilation, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Webpacker (5.1.1) with Rails 6.1.4 takes a long time while compiling css and js files for  existing project and extremely very slow.

**[Web packer] Compiling...**

Environments: Ruby 2.7.2, Node(v14.15.5), NPM 6.14.11 and yarn 1.22.4

This happens once there is no problem, i.e. when the server starts and initiating the first request.

The problem is, it starts compiling whenever I change the code in js or css and takes again the same time around 4/5 minutes.
I think compiling everything instead of the modified file.
I also tried live reloading `./bin/webpack-dev-server`, It also produced the same result.

After doing Google, I tried a few steps below but to no avail

> rm -rf node_modules rake assets:clobber yarn install

Did I miss any configuration/package related to compilation. package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.1.1",
    "@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme": "^1.3.4",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
    "date-arithmetic": "^4.0.1",
    "dom-helpers": "^3.4.0",
    "dotdotdot-js": "^4.0.9",
    "easyzoom": "^2.5.2",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.9.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.0",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-bar-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "jquery-countdown": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.7",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "odometer": "^0.4.8",
    "pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker": "^4.17.50",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "rails-ujs": "^5.2.4-2",
    "rc-time-picker": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-actioncable-provider": "^1.0.3",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-cropper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "git://github.com/sivakovigor/react-custom-scrollbars.git",
    "react-dates": "git://github.com/ihar-lapitski/react-dates.git#feature/change-month-on-date-change",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dotdotdot": "^1.2.3",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.1.4",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
    "react-geosuggest": "^2.12.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.5.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^2.2.0",
    "react-overlays": "^1.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^6.0.0",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.0",
    "react-player": "^1.7.1",
    "react-rating": "^1.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-rnd": "^9.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-select": "^2.4.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^7.1.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.4.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "recompose": "^0.27.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "scroll": "^2.0.3",
    "scroll-doc": "^0.2.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "startbootstrap-sb-admin": "^4.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "uncontrollable": "^7.0.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^5.0.0",
    "validator": "^10.6.0",
    "vanilla-lazyload": "^12.0.0",
    "webp-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.4"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/speed-measure-webpack-plugin plugin to see bottleneck and maybe update your question like that.